# intelligent vscode "Go to Definition"

Tags: visual-studio-code, navigation, shortcut

--- edit

Let's say that I have the following scenario in vscode:

[image: Example]

I have 3 open files, with vscode showing two files at once.
on the left I have 2 tabs: `a.js`, in foreground, with

```js
import { b } from './b';
import { c } from './c';

b();
c();
```

and `b.js`, with

```js
export function b() {
    // ...
}
```

and on the right I have `c.js`, with

```js
export function c() {
    // ...
}
```

My goal is:

- starting from `a.js` as current focused editor
- to have a shortcut - ideally ctrl-click - that

  - when I click on `b()` takes the tab with `b.js` in foreground and focuses on the `function b() {` definition
  - when I click on `c()`, move the focus on the right side, with `c.js` in foreground, and focuses on the `function c() {` definition.
- keep in mind that I DO NOT want to use different shortcuts. This is a simplified example (normally I have multiple tabs AND multiple columns opened) but normally I don't know where the target is, and definitely I don't want the same file opened multiple times.

Is there a way to get it?

--- original

In vscode, according to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition

> You can jump to the definition with Ctrl+Click or open the definition to the side with Ctrl+Alt+Click.

Now, I use the side panel a lot, and sometimes the "target" where the definition is, is in another side, and sometimes is a different tab in the same side on where I am now.

If I do the appropriate choice I can go directly to the already opened buffer. If I choose the "wrong" shortcut a new buffer of the same file is opened.

Is there a way to make the "go to definition" smart? I just want to *always* go to the already opened file (if is available).

Comment: Check out the `Reveal If Open` setting in `Workbench --> Editor Management`. It might do the trick.

Comment: I think this could be edited to be a bit more clear about what it means by "sides" and "buffers" (seems more like vim terminology?). I'm assuming it mean ["editor groups"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_editor-groups), which is more official vscode terminology. It might help to also be a bit more clear about what the "shortcut" being referred to is. This is one of those scenarios where a screenshot with labels could actually help.

Comment: @starball did the updated question is more explicit?

Comment: IDK, Maybe you edited the question, but I disagree with @starball how could you possibly be more concise. This is a well authored question.

Comment: @JΛYDΞV I didn't say "concise" anywhere in my comment. My comment was a request for clarity-in and adherence-to-conventional _terminology_. An edit was made which addressed my suggestion for a screenshot, but my suggestions concerning terminology were not addressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should head to VS Code's settings and select the `Reveal If Open` option.

You'll be able to find it in the `Workbench --> Editor Management` section.

[image: Reveal If Open Setting]